# Why the dynamic programming solution only works for squre board?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

The problem is:

> Given exact k steps, how many ways to move a point from start point to destination? Point can move for eight directions(horizontally, vertically, diagonally, anti-diagonally).

I solved the problem through DP, but it works only for square board, not for rectangle board. I mean if `dim[0]!=dim[1]` in the code, it will run into an error result.

Here I can provide test case:

- Test case 1

  ```
  dim = {5,6},start = {0,2},end = {2,2},steps = 4;
  ```

  result is 50(expected: 105)
- Test case 2

  ```
  dim = {5,5},int[] start = {0,2},end = {2,2},steps = 4;
  ```

  result is 105(expected: 105)

Here is the code:

```
private static int[][] dir =  {{0,1},{1,0},{1,1},{1,-1},{0,-1},{-1,0},{-1,-1},{-1,1}};
//DP
/*
@param dim, a tuple (width, height) of the dimensions of the board
@param start, a tuple (x, y) of the king's starting coordinate
@param target, a tuple (x, y) of the king's destination
 */
public static int countPaths2(int[] dim, int[] start, int[] des, int steps){
    if(dim[0] == 0 || dim[1] == 0) return 0;
    int[][][] dp = new int[dim[0]*dim[1]][dim[1]*dim[0]][steps+1];
    for(int step = 0; step<=steps;step++){
        for(int i = 0; i< dim[0]*dim[1];i++){
            for(int j = 0; j< dim[0]*dim[1];j++){
                if(step == 0 && i == j){
                    dp[i][j][step] = 1;
                }
                if(step >= 1){
                    for(int k =0; k< dir.length;k++){
                        int row = i / dim[0];
                        int col = i % dim[1];
                        if(row + dir[k][0] >= 0 && row + dir[k][0]< dim[0] && col + dir[k][1]>=0 && col + dir[k][1]< dim[1]){
                            int adj = (row + dir[k][0])*dim[0] + col + dir[k][1];
                            dp[i][j][step] += dp[adj][j][step-1];

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int startPos = start[0]*dim[0] + start[1];
    int targetPos = des[0]*dim[0] + des[1];
    return dp[startPos][targetPos][steps];

}


public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] dim = {5,5};  // can just use to square;
    int[] start = {0,2};
    int[] end = {2,2};
    int steps = 7;
    System.out.println(countPaths2(dim, start,end, steps));

}
```

How could I make it work for any kind of board?

Comment: What are i and j?

Comment: i and j represent positions in the board respectively. I just convert the coordinates to a num.for example (1,2) in the board is converted to 1*dim[0]+2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is:

```
int row = i / dim[0];
int col = i % dim[1]; // <- this should have been dim[0]
```

in the div/mod pattern you are supposed to divide and modulo by the same number...

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! That’s where the problem lies.